# Jquery Autocomplete: Multiple Values from SQL DB

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement jqueryui's autocomplete for multiple values but am having trouble. Options pop up fine when I first begin typing a name, but once that name is selected, a comma is added to the list and I no longer get options as I type. The code I have is below.

```
$(function() {
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" )
  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
  $('.theme').autocomplete({
            source:'../../assets/php/themedata.php', 
            minLength:2,
                            width: 300,

    focus: function() {
      // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li />")
        .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
        .append("<a><img src='" + item.avatar + "' />" + item.value + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

themedata.php

```
$st = DB::singleton()
    ->prepare(
        'select * ' .
        'from themes ' .
        'where theme like :theme ' .
        'order by theme asc ' .
        'limit 0,10');

$themeZip = '%' . $_REQUEST['term'] . '%';
$st->bindParam(':theme', $themeZip, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$data = array();
if ($st->execute())
{
   while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
$data[] = array(
    'label' => $row->theme . " , " . $row->desc ,
    'value' => $row->theme 
 );
 }
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
 flush();
```

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/AuqrL/

Comment: Hi thanks for the jsfiddle, how do I include my source:'../../assets/php/themedata.php', into that code?

Comment: im getting the tags from a sql db, not a hard coded array

Comment: come to this chatroom http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42482/web-developers

Comment: just add your json php file path in your input list value as per the jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#theme" )
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.getJSON( "../../assets/php/themedata.php", {
                term: extractLast( request.term )
            }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
            // custom minLength
            var term = extractLast( this.value );
            if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join( ", " );
            return false;
        }
    });
```